# Hystrix circuit is always open even though external system is back online

Tags: java, hystrix

We have added few external system to our app. And We are using Hystrix command to execute the remote REST call using apache http client library.

We are having an issue such that for one external server circuit is always open and we get default fallback. Decreasing sleep window doesn't really help

```
public Command(CloseableHttpClient httpClient, HttpRequestBase httpRequest) {
        super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("MyServer"))
                .andThreadPoolKey(HystrixThreadPoolKey.Factory
                        .asKey(ServerManager.WorkManager.name())));
        ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty(
                "hystrix.command.Command.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds",
                getExecutionTimeout());
        ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance().setProperty(
                "hystrix.command.Commad.circuitBreaker.sleepWindowInMilliseconds",
                getIgnoreTimeout());

        this.httpRequest = httpRequest;
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
}
```

For other systems then circuit breaker is working as expected. 
Tried to restart the application server even after that the circuit breaker seems to be open.

Is there an edge case scenario or something? Or Hystrix command should be handled differently?

Answer (score 1):

Problem was not with Hystrix rather it was with the http connection leak. Http connection's were not released back to pool. So there was a connection leak.